# Entity Framework 6: filter a table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I', approaching to EF6. I have understood that, if I want a single record, I can use the `First()` method (usable also like a "get", I think).

But what if I want a collection of records from my table? I mean, if the result of query can have a cardinality from 0 to N... what have I to do?

Silly Example:

Name table: SomeTable

```
ID    NAME    SOMEATTR
1      A       YELLOW
2      B        RED
3      C       YELLOW
4      D       YELLOW
5      E        BLUE
```

...

How can I get all the records where someAttr is "yellow"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using linq & C#

```
private readonly myEntities db = new myEntities()
public list<SomeTable> MyRecords()
{
 return res = db.SomeTables.where(o => o.SOMEATTR == "YELLOW").ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your Linq query...

```
var query = (from ... in ... where ... select ...);
```

Or, for your specific example:

```
var query = (from r in dbContext.MyTable where (r.someAttr == "YELLOW") select r);
```

You can either just iterate over it using `foreach` which will cause it to be executed once and then yield the results ...

```
foreach (var r in query)
{
}
```

... or call `ToList()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) if you want to acquire a list that can, later, be passed around, manipulated or examined many times. (This list is essentially disconnected from the server after it is returned.)

```
var list = query.ToList()
```

... or use it to construct a collection like a `HashSet<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var set = new HashSet<T>(query)
```

Any of these will cause it to be executed on the server, only once, and process the results.

After all, the query itself is `IEnumerable`. It is also `IQueryable` so you could manipulate it further and *then* enumerate the results, like...

```
var sortedList = query.OrderBy(...).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `SOMEATTR` class that maps to `SOMEATTR` table, you can query it:

```
var context = new YourDbContext();
var results = context.SomeTables.Where(x=>x.SOMEATTR == "Yellow").ToList();

//then you can iterate all results
foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ID + " " + item.NAME + " " + item.SOMEATTR);
}
```

The result will be:

```
1      A       YELLOW
3      C       YELLOW
4      D       YELLOW
```